# How can I set up mongodb to scale it quickly on AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, mongodb

I want to deploy a database using mongodb on AWS, and I think this database will receive a lot of data making necessary to think on the possibility that one server is not enough, so my questions is:

Is it possible to use the elastic compute cloud (EC2) to launch new servers with the database automatically and without stop the service of the other server?

Comment: Of course, you can use a configuration management service ( Ansile, Chef, Puppet, Rex) to launch the ec2 with the database ( cloned or adding a new shard in the cluster ) see this [link](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/platforms/amazon-ec2/) for more details.